# multithreaded server: SwingWorker Vs Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

is all in the title :
I create a java client , that sends a message to server when I click a button , several client can connect in same time,here is my source code:

the client:

```
  private void simulerMessageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    try {
        log.append("wait for connexion..\n");
        socket=new Socket(ip.getText(),Integer.parseInt(port.getText()));

        log.append("Connexion to the server ok");

         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new  InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())  ); ligne.      
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true); 


         String str = "test1";
         log.append("\n"+str+"\n");
         out.println(str); 


         in.close();
         out.close();
         socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Simulator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Simulator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }






  }
```

the server :

```
  private void demarreActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
  sw=new SwingWorker<String,Void> (){

  protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
    try {

            server = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(port.getText()));
      } catch (IOException ex) {
    return "already in use";

        }    
            String str1="waiting for connexion";
            String str2="Connexion ok";

            log.append(str1+"\n");
            PrintWriter out=null;
            BufferedReader in=null;
            Socket socClient=null;
     while(ecoute){
       try{
          socClient = server.accept();  
         }catch(java.net.SocketException e){

           return "[user] Server Stoped";
          }
                    log.append(str2+"\n");
                     in = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(socClient.getInputStream())
                                   );
                   out = new PrintWriter(
                     new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socClient.getOutputStream())), 
                     true);
                    String str = in.readLine();
                    log.append(str+"\n");



         }



     return "fatal error";
       }

       protected void done(){
       String m="";
            try {
                m=get();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        log.append(m+"\n");

        }
      };
    sw.execute();
   }
```

Currently my server contains a small error when I send a message it works, but after that  all the received messages are null...see :
[image]

I think the problem comes from  ​​that I did not create a thread after   `socClient = server.accept();` in server ?
if it's the case what would be best ?:

- *use SwingWorker in a SwingWorker.*
- *create a classic thread with the Runnable interface.*

else what is the solution to overcome this problem ?
Thanks ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use a SwingWorker in this case.  You should have the background processing thread call SwingUtilities.invokeLater() when it's ready to update the GUI.  Typically SwingWorker is for things initiated by GUI events, like clicking a button or menu item so that the GUI will not hang and you can get updates into the GUI over time.  The important piece is making sure your GUI updates are done on the EDT, and SwingUtilities.invokeLater() will handle that.  As alternatives to a basic Thread/Runnable, take a look at Future, Callable, and Executors too, that might give you some ideas how to structure this.  SwingWorker uses them internally.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to create a thread that loops, and each iteration read from the inputstream, something similar to this:

//

```
thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();

public void run() {

            while(true){
                System.out.println("thread is running");
                try {
                    String temp = in.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(temp);
                    chattArea.append(temp);
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }

            }       
    }
```

If you don't do this, input will be read only once

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {  }` why?

Comment: You are also closing the streams right after a message is sent/recived on the client and server. As far as I can tell, that means that after a message is sent, the streams are closed and you won't be able to write / read from them again

Comment: It is a violation of swing threading policy to update a GUI component from outside the Event Dispatch Thread, so at least wrap the chattArea.append(temp) in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater().  If you don't the results are upredictable, chat text out of order, corrupt painting, etc.